# Is it any other API or delegate method available when a text message arrived in ios 7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

Is it possible to get any notification when a text message received from my ios 7 application?
In [Message UI Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MessageUI_Framework_Reference/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008274),API available only to send Text message.Is it any other API or delegate method available when a text message arrived and get the sender mobile number and message body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not available in iOS, this would lead some serieus privacy issues.